# How to pass parameters to annotation with macro expansions

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I'm using [macros annotation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) for generating code. I would like to change its behaviour based on additional string parameters. So it would produce different results for same code.  I closely followed the guide for macro annotations that covers only the simplest use.

```
@myMacros
class MyClass {
}
```

That is how I'm using macroses now. And what I'd like to achieve:

```
@myMacros(name : String)
class MyClass {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use macroApplication

```
class AnnotationPassVal(val name: String) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro AnnotationPassValImpl.apply
}

class AnnotationPassValImpl(val c: Context) {

  import c.universe._

  def showInfo(s: String) =
    c.info(c.enclosingPosition, s.split("\n").mkString("\n |---macro info---\n |", "\n |", ""), true)

  def apply(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*) = {
    val a = c.macroApplication

    //look macroApplication is what 
    showInfo(show(a))


    val AnnotationName: Tree = a match {
      case q"new AnnotationPassVal(name = $name).macroTransform(..$a)" =>
        name: Tree
    }

    showInfo(show(AnnotationName))
    q"""{..$annottees}"""
  }
}
```

test

```
@AnnotationPassVal(name = "hello")
class AnnotationPassValTest //when show info "hello"
```

Comment: and recommended you use tag `scala-macros` , will easier find the question